# Asynctask a bitmap and sqlite issue

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, android-asynctask

I use a library that set an bimap into an ImageView:

**The library:** https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
imageLoader.displayImage(urlString, imageView,  options);
```

its do an asynctask do download and set this bitmap into imageView.
The problem is that after it, I need to store using sqlite:

```
 BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap photo = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
    db.updateUser(imageInByte);
    db.close();
```

So while imageLoader is doing the task, the program store the default image instead of the downloaded one. Also, put this code inside an Asyntask and try to store the bitmap inside onPostexecute(); throws me an error inside the library.

I don´t want to use another library, maybe a looping should be good, I tried:

```
while (((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap() == BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_stub)) {
Log.d("MyApp", "whileloop");
}
```

So, How can I create a "wait"/loop to check when the image is downloaded and store it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: @Geobits, its better now?

Comment: If you specify which image loader library you're using, people will be more able to help.

Comment: Maybe you can tell a bit more about this library? Do you have access to the ASyncTask so you can tell when it is finished? What interface do you have? How is the imageView setup before / while the bitmap is downloaded?

Comment: @Matthieu, I just found a option: imageLoader.displayImage(uri, imageView, options, listener) maybe creating a listener should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this do it?

```
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, targetSize, displayOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        loadedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
        db.updateUser(imageInByte);
        db.close();
    }
});
```